# Compare function with Pin and without

Tags: rust

I am trying to understand Pin in Rust https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/.

The main idea is clear
*If we have `Pin<T>` then pointer of type `T` can't be moved*

I am writing a functions with and without `Pin` for `Box`. I have absolutely the same result. How can I change the code to see effect of `Pin`?

```
use std::fmt::{self, Debug};
use std::pin::Pin;

fn foo_pin<T: Debug>(s: Pin<Box<T>>) {
    let copys = s;
    println!("Hi from Box: {:?}", copys); 
    //println!("Hi from Box: {:?}", s); // ERROR borrow of moved value: `s`
}

fn foo<T: Debug>(s: Box<T>) {
    let copys = s;
    println!("Hi from Box: {:?}", copys); 
    //println!("Hi from Box: {:?}", s); // ERROR borrow of moved value: `s`
}

fn main() {
    // i32
    let b = Box::new(1);
    foo_pin(Pin::new(b));

    let b2 = Box::new(2);
    foo(b2);

    /*
    // &str
    let b = Box::new("abc");
    foo_pin(Pin::new(b));

    let b2 = Box::new("123");
    foo(b2);
    */
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the pointer that can't be moved, it's the data it points at.

For example:

```rust
fn foo_pin<T: Debug + Default>(mut s: Pin<Box<T>>) {
    let data_inside: T = std::mem::take(&mut *s); // Can't make this work.
    println!("Hi from Box: {:?}", data_inside);
}

fn foo<T: Debug + Default>(mut s: Box<T>) {
    let data_inside: T = std::mem::take(&mut *s); // Can move the data.
    println!("Hi from Box: {:?}", data_inside);
}
```

However, note that the pinning contract only applies to types that does not implement [`Unpin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Unpin.html), so not types like `i32` or `&str`. However, the functions are generic and does not require `Unpin`, so this still demonstrates the idea. If we require `Unpin` this works:

```rust
fn foo_pin<T: Debug + Default + std::marker::Unpin>(mut s: Pin<Box<T>>) {
    let data_inside: T = std::mem::take(&mut *s); // Works.
    println!("Hi from Box: {:?}", data_inside);
}
```